# How do I add a manual over-ride into my trigger?

Tags: apex, trigger

In a nutshell, when any user in my organization manually updates the lead field Rate_Total__c, the trigger should never fire again on that lead. Even upon future updates, the trigger should no longer work. It is a before trigger.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a checkbox field on Lead, call it "Rate_Total_Edited__c" or something, default to false. In the trigger, you add a logical check at the beginning and only execute the trigger logic if the checkbox is false. At the end of the trigger logic, you perform another logical check, comparing the new and old value for Rate_Total__c on each record, and if it has changed, you set the checkbox to true. Something like this:

```
for (Lead l : Trigger.new) {
    Lead oldLead = Trigger.oldMap.get(l.Id);

    if (oldLead.Rate_Total__c != l.Rate_Total__c) {
        l.Rate_Total_Edited__c = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahhh. I had tunnel-vision! I was assuming this had to be done within the trigger. Very clever. Thank you!

Comment: I have one question @brianMansfield. Because the trigger's main purpose is to update the value in Rate_Total__c, how will this clause know the difference between a trigger-generated update, and a manual user triggered update? I apologize for not including those details in the question

Comment: I can't immediately think of a solution to this @AlexBrigham, I suggest posting another question, there will definitely be people that have suggestions. It feels like there **should** be a way to achieve this using a static context variable, but I can't figure it out right now...